# Logging ICMP Packets with Iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

I am learning about iptables and I am hitting a wall here.

My task is to log ICMP Requests and Replies from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.1

That's why I added this rule

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 --source 192.168.1.2 -j LOG
```

and

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -d 192.168.1.2 -j LOG
```

It seems to log the requests when I ping from 192.168.1.2 on 192.168.1.1

But it fails to log the replies. Any ideas why?

// Edit

```
bash-5.1# iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Apr  1 09:20:45 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
[43:3612] -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.2/32 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOG
[37:3108] -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.2/32 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j LOG
COMMIT
```

Not sure why both rules are in OUTPUT ACCEPT, but it looks like this with `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        icmp --  192.168.1.2          anywhere             icmp echo-request LOG level warning

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        icmp --  anywhere             192.168.1.2          icmp echo-reply LOG level warning
```

Comment: Can you [include](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/697610/edit "edit") your current complete ruleset shown with this command: `iptables-save -c`?

Comment: I added the ruleset

Comment: And the system with these rules has IP address 192.168.1.1/24 right?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Then indeed I'm a bit baffled (and you get a +1)

Comment: In regards to your comment "Not sure why both rules are in OUTPUT ACCEPT", I don't think the rules are in "OUTPUT ACCEPT".  iptables-save starts by listing the table name (which is "filter" in your case), then it lists the default policy (DROP or ACCEPT) for the built-in chains, then it lists all of the rules.  The "-A" in the rule, will tell you which chain the rule belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to ping from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.1, OUTPUT chain will be used to scan sending requests and INPUT chain will be used to scan receiving responses, so correct iptables would be created as follows:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -s 192.168.1.2 -j LOG
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -d 192.168.1.2 -j LOG
```